# Why is it so hard to get out of jail?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I get 4 downvotes from a question and my account gets banned from asking a question. I work my tail off to get these upvotes, but rarely does anyone vote for my answers, even when they are detailed and right. Even after increasing my rep by 100 points, I'm still banned.

So what gives? Shouldn't it be somewhat easier to get out of jail, because its sure easy to get in there.

Comment: You're banned from asking questions, so revising your answers is going to have a lot less impact than revising your questions would.

Comment: @BilltheLizard they are all deleted. i didnt' have answers downvoted, but questions i asked. especially early on when i was still green. almost all of my questions were downvoted. now anytime i get a downvote, it sticks for months

Comment: If you had read any of the meta posts that already exist about question bans you'd know that deleting a question doesn't mean that it doesn't count anymore. You're going to need to go back and try to improve those old questions if you want to get your account back into good standing.

Comment: When you get out of a ban it doesn't wipe the slate clean. You are right on the edge of being banned again. You shouldn't immediately start posting questions again if you're not going to work to make sure they're high-quality questions.

Comment: Kudos for managing to increase your reputation and trying to get out of the ban though. I've made some minor edits to your question here. Especially with regards to proper capitalization, keep that in mind and apply it yourself as well. If it looks half decent, you're less likely to be a downvote target.

Comment: @Bart thanks man. I rarely need to ask a question any more, but when i come across something in bash that i can't figure out it'd be nice to be able to ask without infuriating the people @ askubuntu.

Comment: just make a new account ?

Comment: Nope @Shqiptar_Programmer. Bad idea. That will see you banned again. Circumventing a ban is never the answer.

Comment: @Shqiptar_Programmer: you're a genius! Why didn't anyone else think of that before? .... or maybe they have already, and maybe following your suggestion can just get the poster to dig an even deeper hole. A better suggestion: get rid of your very bad suggestion.

Comment: @sphanley alot of them were not improvable. i was green and asking stupid questions. the one that triggered the latest ban was a code example i picked up from a tutorial. the code had hidden Unicode characters in it and i couldn't figure out what was triggering the error. obviously, there is no improving such a question. it was a designed trap by the tutorial author.

Comment: FYI, if you actually do understand why those early questions were awful (and a track record of NOT asking awful questions/giving good answers afterwards is generally an indicator of this) you can probably get the worst of the deleted questions off your back by asking...

Comment: @Will already asked, they said no. sent repeated emails.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels While the recommendation by Shqiptar_Programmer is definitely not the right way to go and I consider it borderline offensive, the problem is that it works and is by far the simplest way to gain back the privilege to ask questions. See for example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283365/1110381 where the user admits he created at least 5 accounts to evade question bans; and their latest account had **11** questions. Following that suggestion does not seem to "get the poster to dig an even deeper hole" at all.

Comment: Depends on who you ask.  Mods can't do this, I'll tell you that.  But if you ask the right people, they can't say no.  Go look through the [meta-tag:faq] tag.

Answer (score 7):

Difficulty is relative.  It's all about how easy it is for you to create valuable contributions.  Some people really struggle to create quality content that other users find valuable, while others just don't.  If you're *really* struggling to dig yourself out of the hole then it's going to have more to do with your ability to create content that helps other people, more so than any particular interaction of the system itself.

As far as the system is concerned, it's quite a bit *easier* to get out of a ban than to get into one; it takes quite a bit of work to get yourself banned.  Positive contributions help one quite a lot more than negative contributions hurt you.  A user providing an equal amount of positive and negative contributions is going to be nowhere near being post banned.  It is only when negative contributions greatly outweigh the positive contributions that the post ban is reached.

If you honestly just can't create content that others are finding valuable, and are consequently in a ban, then *the system is working as intended*.

Comment: go look at my answers. people rarely upvote, because there is no reward for upvoting good content.

Comment: @r3wt In all of my experiences people give upvotes very freely for even mediocre content.  People tend to only downvote the worst of the worst.  Getting bad content to actually get downvotes is very hard in all of my experiences.  If you're *really* struggling to get upvotes for your content, then that just tells that your content isn't worth upvoting, not that people are refusing to upvote good content.  Either that or you're posting in very obscure tags with extremely low traffic (which doesn't appear to be the case here), which will result in few votes in general, due to so few views.

Comment: read the comments under the OP please. when i first signed up for the site, i was green. IE, i knew absolutely nothing. my first 5 or 6 question were pathetic. eventually i came back and started making positive contributions. a month or so ago, i asked a question that got 4 downvotes. hidden charachters causing error in javascript. that's how i got banned. not giving poor answers. poor questions. i'm trying to get out of jail man but i'm having a tough go of it.

Comment: @r3wt I stand by my answer.  If you're able to provide positive contributions that people find valuable, you shouldn't have any problems.  If you can't, then you will struggle, *by design*.

Comment: well your answer is wrong. the system is unfairly weighted.

Comment: @r3wt As I said in my answer, the system *is* unfairly weighted, **in the direction of getting you out of the ban**.  It takes *far* less valuable content to get out of the ban than it takes crap content to get you into it.

Comment: Not to be "that guy" @r3wt, but could you please properly capitalize what you write as I suggested? It would immediately improve what you write.

Comment: Servy, have you ever been banned? I received 4 down votes on the question that resulted in my ban. I've gotten 10 up votes since then. I am still banned after months.

Comment: @r3wt Votes on answers understandably have much less impact on your ability to ask questions than votes on questions.  No, I have not been banned, although I pay attention to a lot of other users' cases when it comes up on meta (as it does almost every day).  Pretty much anyone actually trying to create quality content, and putting in a solid effort, tends to have no problem with post bans, in my experiences.  The only people who seem to get them are the people who don't care about providing valuable content to others.

Comment: @Servy i disagree.

Comment: R3wt Please start to CAPITALIZE proper letters, beginning of the sentence included as Bart twice suggested and you declined that (valuable) suggestion in most of your posts here. @Servy Users participating in more localized tags may in fact suffer from the low size of the active audience to get more views and, consequently, more chances to receive upvotes for valuable content (i.e particular framework vs widely used language). Though, OP's case seems different.

Comment: @skuntsel Being in a smaller community is going to need less votes in general *of all types*.  While users are going to get less upvotes for good content, they're also going to get less downvotes for bad content, so it tends to even out.  If you post a bunch of bad content in a popular tag though, you'd need to work harder posting good content if you move into less popular tags.

Comment: _"read the comments under the OP please. when i first signed up for the site, i was green. IE, i knew absolutely nothing."_ Using standard English will go a long way to preventing some downvotes. Sentences start with a capital letter. The first-person pronoun "I" is _always_ capitalized. The abbreviation "i.e.", which stands for the Latin _id est_ (or "that is") shouldn't be written in all caps. I will wager that a fair number of the downvotes (or non-upvotes) your content attracts is due to your "use" of the language.